# MacBook Pro 13" Mid-2010 - upgrade HDD to SDD with intermittent Prohibitory sign

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, ssd

Good morning folks,

I can't wrap my head around this one.

I recently upgraded a failing 250 GB HDD to a 1 TB SSD and transitioned the data using a hard drive duplicator.

When starting from a cold start, the computer boots fine and works very well.
However, when starting from a restart, the computer shows the prohibitory sign forcing me to turn off the computer. Since the subsequent start is a cold start, it then works fine again.

Does anyone have any insight as to why a system reboot would cause this behavior?

The OS is Sierra.
SDD was checked and repaired using DiskWarrior.
Apple Hardware Diagnostics reported "No trouble found"

It may help to note that the original HDD was throwing an I/O error in verbose mode and would not boot, but was able to be copied with a duplicator to the new SSD.

Thanks mate!

Comment: What kind of 'duplicator'?

Comment: Like this, but an older model: https://www.amazon.com/Aluratek-External-Portable-Duplicator-AHDDUB100/dp/B002FJJMAI

Comment: I have no clue how that would actually transfer the data. One of the QAs underneath says you need to use CCC or similar for Mac drives, which makes me think it's just a file copier which can't natively read HFS or APFS itself. It does make me suspect your SATA cable, rather than either of the drives themselves.

Comment: I've used it successfully before for other Macbook hard drive upgrades. I also started to suspect the SATA cable :-(

Comment: If you've used it successfully on multiple occasions, then I'm down to 'SATA cable' too. If it aint the duper, it's something else. 2 drives, similar symptoms... the weak link is...

Comment: Have you done the SMC and NVRAM resets?  I kind of doubt its the sata cable because doing a cold boot wouldn't do anything to an electrical issue only letting it cool down or something like that would change the physical properties.  Also, unless abused, they rarely go bad.  The mechanical drive is old enough to go bad so I am less inclined to say its the same issue on two drives.  As far as the drive cloner.  We have used them lots with no issue.  It is a sector by sector copier and doesn't care about file systems and it does an awesome job of duplicating drives that are throwing errors.

Comment: I did SMC and NVRAM resets. I swapped out the 1TB Samsung QVO 860 for a Kingston 240GB A400 SSD and installed a fresh copy of High Sierra; it works every time. I then duplicated the known working Kingston to the Samsung drive and received the same results. I should mention that the Kingston drive appears to be a bit slower than the Samsung. Is it possible that the drive is too fast for a possibly degraded cable? I ordered a new cable anyway and I will report back the results :-) Also, I can boot the Samsung drive from USB without incident.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be the cable. I just installed a new one. I will post my progress once I order a new 1TB HDD. I have always had success with the EVO. Maybe that makes a difference. Very odd behaviour.

Comment: I just installed the EVO drive and it works well, without incident. Has anyone had the same experience?